# Jmol applet error 404

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to embed a Jmol applet in a webpage, and I am testing it from a virtual machine, but everytime I refresh the webpage I get this error in the konsole

**127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2013 19:41:42] "GET /static/Jmol/Jmol.js HTTP/1.1" 404 758*

the source code that I have used is this:

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is the source code <script src=".../.../Jmol/Jmol.js><script>

Comment: Suggest you ask the question on blueobelisk.shapado.com/ and give greater details

Comment: Please give us a code sample

Comment: This is the code that I am using for the applet                           <form>
         <script type="text/javascript">
   jmolInitialize("/home/mahnoor/Desktop/fridb/Jmol/", window.location.protocol=="file:");
    jmolSetCallback("UseCommandThread","true");
    jmolApplet(200, "load /home/mahnoor/Desktop/fridb/Jmol/bnp/POSCAR.xyz" , "one");
        </script>
      </form>

Comment: *"trying to embed a Jmol applet in a webpage,"*  Wat is the URL (of the web page)?  And what is 'Jmol'?  When there is no tag for it, it is a good hint to link..